# NSOutputStream flushing

Tags: flush, nsstream

I'm working on an iPhone App and wanted to use:

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, url, port, &serverReadStream, &serverWriteStream);
```

And after that use the:

```
[serverWriteStream write:[sendData bytes] maxLength:[sendData length]];
```

I want to send small Packages of 5 Bytes to get realtime updates.

My problem is now, that the stream only sends data when the buffer is full. So I need some kind of a flush method or tell the stream to immediately send the data.

Searching for this problem ended in finding 'TCP_NODELAY' which seems to belong to the undocumented API ( which I mustn't use for AppStore, correct me if im wrong pls ) and even if I might be allowed to use it, I would have to change the creation of the streams, right?

Answer (score 5):

[Cocoa NSOutputStream send to a connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589070/cocoa-nsoutputstream-send-to-a-connection)

Just add an "end of line" ( "\n" ) to your string. work for me.

Comment: In some cases the best solution is "\r\n" sequence.

Comment: What if data is not a string?