# ios writing fast to stream

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm having problems when looping the code below:

```
    NSString *response  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"id\":\"%@\",\"type\":\"%@\",\"msg\":\"%@\"}",userID, method, msg];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
```

This is how i open the stream:

```
// Open connection to server
- (void)initNetworkCommunication {
    isConnected = TRUE;
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"url.com", 8080, &readStream, &writeStream);
    inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];

    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
}
```

The problem is that when writing to the stream fast it combines all messages into one, my server can only parse one `JSON` at the time.

Is there a way to implement that only 1 `response` string is sent at a time? Like a queue?

How do people usually solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you 'flush' your output stream that should solve your problem. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807191/nsoutputstream-flushing) is a similar question  that suggests you add "\n" or "\r\n" to your string to flush it.