# Streaming Accelerometer data via NSNetService

Tags: ios, swift, network-programming, streaming, bonjour

I'm trying to stream the accelerometer data of one iOS device to another iOS device and I'm having some issues with that.

The basic communication already works, let's say on a button press or button release.

Server part:

```
    self.server = NSNetService(domain: "local.", type: kWiTapBonjourType, name: UIDevice.currentDevice().name, port: 0)        
    self.server?.includesPeerToPeer = true;
    self.server?.delegate = self
    self.server?.publishWithOptions(NSNetServiceOptions.ListenForConnections)
```

Client part:

```
    NSString *pit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",pitch];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[pit dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    bytesWritten = [self.outputStream write:data.bytes maxLength:[data length]];
```

Now it gets sent to the server, where I'm reacting to the Client's values:

```
    var buffer = Array<UInt8>(count: 16, repeatedValue: 0)
    var output = ""
    while (self.inputStream!.hasBytesAvailable){
        let bytesRead: Int = inputStream!.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
        if bytesRead >= 0 {
             output += NSString(bytes: UnsafePointer(buffer), length: bytesRead, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
        } else {
             print("# error")
        }
        print("> \(output)")
    }
```

And now here's the log:

```
> -0.29
> -0.24
> -0.26-0.29-0.29
> -0.22
> -0.11
> 0.00
> 0.080.14
> 0.21
> 0.28
> 0.33
> 0.360.38
> 0.37
> 0.38
> 0.38
> 0.37
> 0.360.36
> 0.35
> 0.320.300.300.30
> 0.320.300.300.300.300.29
```

As you can see, the data from the client gets kinda put together. I assume that's just how streaming works - unfortunately I don't know that much about streaming, I'm trying to learn things about it but I need to get it up and running asap

How can I improve my code to make this work? I was already thinking about adding some sort of delimiter after each value, like some special String and then split it back up accordingly in the server part. But I was not sure if that's really the correct way of doing things.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like NSOutputStream will write to its own buffer until some condition is met, which is why the number of results varies

Comment: Adding a delimiter is a good idea, but you could also add a newline which should cause the outputStream to flush its buffers and send: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7394904/78496

Comment: Thanks! I will try this today.

Comment: Ok this seems to work, thanks for your input, guys. But it seems like there are some packets getting lost. Sometimes there are quite big "holes" in my stream, which causes inaccurate reactions on the server. I'm trying to rotate a simple object on the server based on the accelerometer data of the client device. What can I do about that?