# NSOutputStream flush

Tags: objective-c, flush, nsstream

I want to send small packages using the NSOutputStream in Objective-C.

I have the same problem this user has:
[Cocoa NSOutputStream send to a connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589070/cocoa-nsoutputstream-send-to-a-connection)

An answer is to just add "\n" to the end of the string.
I tried so and it does not work.

Does someone of you see my problem there?
Might the encoding be the problem?

```
// Append the line break
theMessage = [theMessage stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];

// Create the data object
NSData *d = [theMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

// Send the message
[self.outputStream write:[d bytes] maxLength:[d length]]
```

Edit: I get the outputstream by calling this method from a NSNetservice-Object:

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, url, port, &inputStream, &outputStream);
```

Edit2: The problem is that if I send a lot of messages very fast, the server recieves the message as one string, not as two seperated

Comment: So what is outputStream initialized as?

Comment: I got it calling the method above

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? You don't give us what your output is or what errors occur or anything. Are you sure that `theMessage` can be encoded in ASCII? If it contains any characters with accents (e.g. `ç`, `é`, etc.) then it won't work when converted to ASCII.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I added the exact problem to the thread. The message can be encoded with ASCII, but I also tried UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.; it does not help