# CFStream connection cannot connect while using public ip

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, cfstream

I am a newbie to iOS and Objective c....
In my app i am establishing a socket connection to my server using the CFStream.. the problem is
when i run my program using the local ip (192.168.10.246) the connection is established, but when i replace it with a public ip the view rather freezes and give the following error event..

I am currently running on the simulator...

```
2013-06-27 12:50:41.778 BarcodeGenerator[446:c07] Start StreamEvent 8
2013-06-27 12:50:41.778 BarcodeGenerator[446:c07] Can not connect to the host!
2013-06-27 12:50:41.779 BarcodeGenerator[446:c07] Start StreamEvent 8
2013-06-27 12:50:41.780 BarcodeGenerator[446:c07] Can not connect to the host!
```

And my code is..

```
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)ip, 54000, &readStream, &writeStream);

    inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];

    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];

    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[pinno dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
    [outputStream close];
```

Do i need to add some extra piece of code for public ip... or is it some kind of a firewall problem in network connection or a setting in Xcode???
Please Help!!!!

```
Edit:
```

I have attached the wireshark logs:
My destination public ip is 221.135.139.46....

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     83 2.426998000    192.168.43.131        221.135.139.46        TCP      78     50853 > 54000 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=16 TSval=61451776 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 83: 78 bytes on wire (624 bits), 78 bytes captured (624 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Apple_13:f4:a1 (00:23:12:13:f4:a1), Dst: SamsungE_75:d9:c7 (94:63:d1:75:d9:c7)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.43.131 (192.168.43.131), Dst: 221.135.139.46 (221.135.139.46)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 50853 (50853), Dst Port: 54000 (54000), Seq: 0, Len: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a firewall related error. Do you forward your public ip to a host? Have you opened the port in the firewall. Test to connect to an known to work public ip before trying to connect to your server.

You need:

> Depending on the level of your router this terminology will be Port
>   Forwarding, Virtual IPs, or Static NAT Translation (there are a few
>   others but you get the idea).

If your android version is working, there might be something else causing the problem. Ray Wenderlich has a good [example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server) of how to implement a stream app. You can analyze what is actually being passed on the network using [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) to analyze further and also look into the router logs. Im unsure since you say android works with the public ip

Comment: i just checked my firewall settings... my firewall is turned off... can you tell me any known public ip for which i can test my connection

Comment: You need to forward the connection, what router/firewall are you using?

Comment: I was using my office net... so i thought it might be protected by some firewall not allowing to establish any public connections... But later i tried by my personal data card net... but still no luck... i have implement a same replica in android using socket connection..its working fine... No idea about iOS

Comment: You need to forward the public ip through the router to the host you want to connect to

Comment: Wireshark logs? You should update your question with the info bout the workng android version and which tutorial you have been using

Comment: Did you get a response from the server at all? Is your android version also on port 54000

Answer (score 0):

This guy has another approach of handling the [write to the NSOutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491499/cannot-write-to-nsoutputstream-immediately-after-it-is-open) His problem sounds similar to yours. The problem is that his app stalls and nothing happens on the line `[outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]]`;